# Добавляя событие на блок перестаёт работать сам input?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$('input[name="check-all"]').on('click', function() {
  let projectId = $(this).attr('data-check-all'),
    checked = $(this).prop('checked'),
    inputs = $('#project-' + projectId + ' input.input-bron');
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    $(inputs[i]).prop('checked', checked);
  }
  if (checked) {
    $('button#btn-change-' + projectId).prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('button#btn-change-' + projectId).prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
$('.brons').on('click', function() {
  let bronId = $(this).attr('data-brone'),
    parent = $(this).parent(),
    projectId = $(parent).attr('data-bc'),
    check = $('input[type="checkbox"]#input-bron-' + bronId).prop('checked');

  $('input[type="checkbox"]#input-bron-' + bronId).prop('checked', !check);

  if (!check) {
    $('button#btn-change-' + projectId).prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    countChecked = $('#brons-container-' + projectId + ' input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    if (countChecked.length > 0) {
      $('button#btn-change-' + projectId).prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('button#btn-change-' + projectId).prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="brons-container-694" class="brons-container" data-bc="694">
  <div id="bron_id-2276" class="row brons color-status-2" data-brone="2276">
    <div class="col-8 col-md-7 col-lg-8 tool-2276">
      <label class="tool_name" for="input-bron-2276" data-count="1">Стул</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 tool-2276">
      <label class="status_name" for="input-bron-2276" data-count="1">Авторизовано</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-md-2 col-lg-1 tool-2276 text-right">
      <label class="padding_5px">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-bron-2276" class="input-bron" name="input-bron-2276" data-count="1" data-check-brone="2276">
   </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bron_id-2277" class="row brons color-status-1" data-brone="2277">
    <div class="col-8 col-md-7 col-lg-8 tool-2277">
      <label class="tool_name" for="input-bron-2277" data-count="2">Кресло</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 tool-2277">
      <label class="status_name" for="input-bron-2277" data-count="2">Не обработано</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-md-2 col-lg-1 tool-2277 text-right">
      <label class="padding_5px">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-bron-2277" class="input-bron" name="input-bron-2277" data-count="2" data-check-brone="2277">
   </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Почему перестают срабатывать `label` и `input`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаю какую логику Вы хотите реализовать, но проблема в строке: `$('input[type="checkbox"]#input-bron-'+bronId).prop('checked',!check);`
Метод `prop('checked')` и так возвращает вам в `checked` `true` или `false`

```js
$('input[name="check-all"]').on('click', function() {
  let projectId = $(this).attr('data-check-all'),
    checked = $(this).prop('checked'),
    inputs = $('#project-' + projectId + ' input.input-bron');
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    $(inputs[i]).prop('checked', checked);
  }
  if (checked) {
    $('button#btn-change-' + projectId).prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('button#btn-change-' + projectId).prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
$('.brons').on('click', function(e) {
  let bronId = $(this).attr('data-brone'),
    parent = $(this).parent(),
    check,
    projectId = $(parent).attr('data-bc'),
    inputCheck = $('input[type="checkbox"]#input-bron-' + bronId);
  if (e.target.tagName === 'DIV') {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]#input-bron-' + bronId).prop('checked', !inputCheck.prop("checked"));
  }
  if (e.target.tagName === 'LABLE') {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  check = inputCheck.prop("checked");
  if (!check) {
    $('button#btn-change-' + projectId).prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    countChecked = $('#brons-container-' + projectId + ' input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    if (countChecked.length > 0) {
      $('button#btn-change-' + projectId).prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('button#btn-change-' + projectId).prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="brons-container-694" class="brons-container" data-bc="694">
  <div id="bron_id-2276" class="row brons color-status-2" data-brone="2276">
    <div class="col-8 col-md-7 col-lg-8 tool-2276">
      <label class="tool_name" for="input-bron-2276" data-count="1">Стул</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 tool-2276">
      <label class="status_name" for="input-bron-2276" data-count="1">Авторизовано</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-md-2 col-lg-1 tool-2276 text-right">
      <label class="padding_5px">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-bron-2276" class="input-bron" name="input-bron-2276" data-count="1" data-check-brone="2276">
   </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bron_id-2277" class="row brons color-status-1" data-brone="2277">
    <div class="col-8 col-md-7 col-lg-8 tool-2277">
      <label class="tool_name" for="input-bron-2277" data-count="2">Кресло</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 tool-2277">
      <label class="status_name" for="input-bron-2277" data-count="2">Не обработано</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-md-2 col-lg-1 tool-2277 text-right">
      <label class="padding_5px">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-bron-2277" class="input-bron" name="input-bron-2277" data-count="2" data-check-brone="2277">
   </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш пример не работает на весь блок `.brons`. А логика такова, что кликнув по любому месту в вышеуказанном блоке устанавливается или снимается галочка. Метод `.prop('checked',!check)` - устанавливает отличное от исходного состояния новое состояние.

Comment: Я поправил ответ.

Comment: При клике по `label` не работает)

Comment: Да, точно ;) Теперь работает.